# Just one letter riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics, wordplay

This riddle is composed with exactly one Greek letter:

> $\color{green}\tau$

This letter describes an amazing and well known result. It is up to you to find out

Good Luck!

Hint:

> Look at the second tag.

P.S this is my first riddle so feel free to suggest improvements/edits.

Comment: Sorry to be critical but you literally just showed a green tau and the answer was "green tau". You even have a hint identifying it as a greek letter and pointed out the tag. Is this a puzzle? Isn't it just like showing a picture of a pink elephant and asking "what's this?" Yes a pink elephant, well done.

Comment: @Astralbee Actually, the answer was the "green **tao theorem**". I agree I misjudged the difficulty of this puzzle though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The green tau refers to the [Green-Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem).

Comment: I hope that wasn't too easy. Any way, Good job!